# Validity of point mass approximation in Newton's laws of motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, point-particles

Chapter 2 of Kleppner & Kolenkow's *An Introduction to Mechanics* reads as follows -

> Newton's Laws describe the behavior of point masses. In the case where the size of the body is small compared with the interaction distance, this offers no problem. For instance, the earth and sun are so small compared with the distance between them that for many purposes their motion can be adequately described by considering the motion of point masses located at the center of each.

Consider a system consisting of a block kept at rest on a table. Assume that friction is neglected. When drawing a force diagram for such a block, we assume it to be a point mass. (Also see: Section 2.4 of Kleppner & Kolenkow's book... Just to mention that such a step is followed in the book itself.)  However, it doesn't seem to me that this assumption is valid, as the interaction distance between the block and the table is so small as compared to their sizes.

Then why is the point mass approximation valid in such a case?

*Note:* This chapter has not generalized Newton's laws to describe rigid bodies yet. So it would be great if you could answer my question without any reference to that (of course, if possible!).

Comment: When you get to the mechanics of extended bodies you'll get the tools to tell you if the physics of point particles is good enough in this case. Though, of course, that isn't very satisfying in the mean time.

Comment: I think K&K could have said a little bit more at this point.   Best for now to take the point of view that you are *modeling* the book as a point particle.  A model keeps properties that are important for the problem at hand, and ignore those that will turn out to be small, or those that are not of interest.  "As simple as possible, but no simpler."

Comment: It's not true that Newton's laws require point masses. All that is required  is that all mass elements of an extended body are moving at the same velocity and that they are experiencing the same acceleration. Point masses don't exist and they should never be mentioned in the teaching of classical mechanics. That's a shoddy way of teaching if there ever was one. What does exist is the particle approximation in which we acknowledge that _extended bodies_ are not rigid, that rotational etc. degrees of motion exist but that we can often enough approximate it by the COM motion. Another doorstop.

Comment: @CuriousOne If you are saying that extended bodies should never be described as point particles in introductory courses  (I hope that's *not* what you are saying), I could not disagree with you more strongly.  Physics is all about making models.   I make this point on day one of my course, and carry the theme throughout.

Comment: @garyp: The objectification of mathematical approximations is one of the worst sins that a textbook author can commit. It's unnecessary, it teaches the students bad mental habits and, most importantly, it's blatantly false both ontologically and mathematically. A point mass is not an object that replaces a real mass. The real, extended mass is, at all times, present in the description of the physical event. We merely replace its motion by the motion of its COM _and_ we adjust all our dynamic vectors to remove the offsets in the displacements of COMs during interactions!

Comment: @garyp - with reference to your first comment: so you are saying that the point particle approximation "just works" for the purpose at hand. Am I right? I wanted to know why does that work i.e. why is the _point mass modeling_ of the block valid, even though the criterion given in the book doesn't seem to hold in this case :\

Comment: @CuriousOne: So if I understood correctly, the "particle approximation" says that the motion of extended bodies can be studied by studying the motion of their center of mass. Tell me if I got wrong somewhere. And this approximation is valid only when "all mass elements of the extended body are moving at the same velocity and that they are experiencing the same acceleration", right? This seems to be valid in my case! So is it that the book is actually using this "particle approximation" here?

Comment: The justification comes, as always, with comparison to experiment.  For example, we usually model our atmosphere as a vacuum.  That is, we ignore air resistance.   Whether or not this is a good model depends on how accurate your measuring equipment is, and what your goals are.  For university physics labs, it's usually justified.

Comment: Also @CuriousOne: do we have a reason as to why the "particle approximation" works well under that condition? I guess I'll be reading about it in the rigid body motion chapter, right? And another thing: could anyone suggest an example of a system for which this approximation cannot be applied?

Comment: For masses which don't rotate too fast and which don't vibrate too much we can replace the actual motion by the motion of the center of mass and not make too large an error. That there can be only one effective velocity and acceleration is a logical consequence of the fact that only one is mentioned in Newton's second law. Where all of this falls apart is when textbooks (and your post) say "_be_ a point mass". "Being" is, ontologically, an expression that assigns an existential property. "A stone is", but a point mass "is" not. "A point mass" is merely a mathematical approximation procedure.

Comment: An approximation works well when it agrees (numerically) with observations. What matters is always a comparison with reality. Now, you can, of course, use the next higher level of theory (i.e. continuum mechanics) to predict when an experiment will agree well with simple Newtonian mechanics, but that, logically, leads to an infinite (and impractical) regression.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are comparing two pretty different cases. Motion of the Earth with respect to the Sun (and vise versa) is different from motion of a block on a table with respect to it. In the former, both of the Earth and Sun experience rotational motion and cannot be assumed as a particle **without approximation error**. But in the later, the block doesn't experience rotational motion and thus can be **exactly** substituted with a particle in the COM and with the same mass.

In the first case (Earth and Sun), we **neglect** rotational motion affects. But in the second case (block), we neglect **nothing** because there is no affects due to rotational motion.

I think the book are talking about approximation not modeling.

Comment: But it says that the planetary motion can well be accounted for by the point particle approximation, even when there is rotational motion, right?

Comment: @AkashBajaj Yes, but there will be an error that is negligible.

Comment: So what is the _reason_ for there being "negligible error" in the case of planetary motion and there being "no error at all" in the block's case?

Comment: @AkashBajaj The reason is rotational motion. Planets experience rotational motion, but the block doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is correct. When considering a block resting on the table the reaction forces do not go through the center of mass (point mass approximation location). See [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/253337/392) and the accompanying diagram for a more realistic picture.

> [image: block on table]

You do find though that for a rigid body, the point approximation is entirely appropriate when modeling *the response of the center of mass*. For example [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DY3LYQv22qY) shows the motion of a tennis racket when thrown across a room. When viewed as a whole body the motion seems very complex, but when the lights turn off and *only the center of mass* is tracked the result is much simpler (a parabola).

The *laws* of motion state that the net force acting on a rigid body equals mass times acceleration *of the center of mass*. When tracking the center of mass it is not only appropriate, but required to consider all the forces acting as if they were passing through the center of mass. Only when rotations are examined the location of the forces (away from the COM) become relevant.